# Backups fail with operating system error 1265

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, domaincontroller

Getting the below error when trying to backup databases:

[image]

I am able to connect to the shared location on the same server, and I can ping the backup server successfully.
Does anyone know why the backups would be failing.
The Backup job runs using the 'sa' user.

Comment: Does the service account that SQL Server runs on have permissions to write to the share?

Comment: Yes, has full permissions

Comment: Good to hear you got it resolved.  That's always a fun one when accounts are getting locked out but you don't know where.  
The domain controller logs should tell you at least which computer the call that locked out the machine was from.  https://www.technipages.com/find-computer-locking-ad-account

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bee_Rii, after checking the file location permissions I asked the AD team to verify that the account is fine, and they told me the account was locked out. After fixing that, the backups started running again.

Now I need to figure out where and why the account got locked, but thats a different issue all together.